# Limits on requesting GPS location using Google Maps API V2

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, google-maps-android-api-2, locationmanager

I am developing an android application that uses the Google Maps API V2. Part of my application requires to request the phones GPS location using the LocationManager. I am under the impression that there is a limit for the number of requests that the application can make.

If there is a limit, can someone tell me what the limit is and what are the costs involved when exceeding the limit?

If this is not correct the forum to post the question, can you kindly direct me to the correct one? I will then subsequently delete this question.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think google provide 25000 limit to use various google api services request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no request-limit for location updates, via the `LocationManager` or `FusedLocationApi`, in general.

Comment: There is no limit for the map api.  But you have some rules to follow.  You can't cover the "google" on the map with a control and the app has to be "publicly available" what ever that means.